# when there is a iframe with zepto inside, a trigger for touchend may lead to an error

Tags: javascript, iframe, zepto

I've build a suit on http://jsfiddle.net/57dZQ/

it seems that the callback of 'touchend' in zepto.js:1340 execute twice

to reproduce this issue, you need to open the 'Emulate touch events' of chrome developer tool

then open http://jsfiddle.net/57dZQ/

and wait for a while, click the iframe whose src is 'zeptojs.com', you will see some error log 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'trigger' of undefined '